# Converting long linear data into data in C by modifying indexes in array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to organize chunks of an apache log file into an array. For example, assume my apache file has a line like this:

```
[a] [b] [ab] [abc] file not found: /something
```

What I want to achieve is an array (let's name it ext) so that:

```
ext[0] = a
ext[1] = b
ext[2] = ab
ext[3] = abc
```

I then reserve enough space for 20 entries at 5000 characters each via:

```
char ext[20][5000];
```

Then I attempt to call my extraction function as follows:

```
extract("[a] [b] [ab] [abc]",18,ext);
```

Ideally, the string is replaced with the variable holding the data and the 18 is replaced with the variable showing the actual string size, but I'm using this data as an example.

The extract function won't compile.

It's complaining that in:

```
char s[20][5000]=*extr,*p,*l=longstring;
```

there's an invalid initializer. I'm guessing `s[20][5000]=*extr` is it, but I'm trying to initialize a character array with index values then I want to pass it onto the function caller

It then complains:

```
warning: passing argument 3 of 'extract' from incompatible pointer type
```

> Am I forced to strictly use pointers and mathematics to calculate offsets or is there a way to pass actual char array with the ability to modify them using index values like I tried to do?

```
long extract(char* longstring,long sz,char **extr){
    unsigned long sect=0,si=0,ssi=0;
    char s[20][5000]=*extr,*p,*l=longstring;
    while (sz-- > 0){
        if (*l=='['){sect=1;p=s[si++];if (si > 20){break;}}
        if (*l==']'){sect=0;}else{
        if (sect==1){*p++=*l;}
        }
        l++;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

As per suggested, I made minor changes and my code is now as follows:

Mainline:

```
char ext[20][5000];
extract("[a] [b] [ab] [abc]",18,(char**)ext);
printf("%s\n",ext);
return 0;
```

Function:

```
long extract(char* longstring, long sz, char **extr) {
    unsigned long sect = 0, si = 0, ssi = 0;
    char **s = extr, *p, *l = longstring;
    while (sz-- > 0) {
        if (*l == '[') {
            sect = 1;
            p = s[si++];
            if (si > 20) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (*l == ']') {
            sect = 0;
        } else {
            if (sect == 1) {
                *p++ = *l;
            }
        }
        l++;
    }
}
```

And now I receive a segmentation fault. I'm not sure why when I set the offset of one string via `p=s[si++]` and then incremented it as I add data. I even changed `p=s[si++]` to `p=s[si++][0]` in an attempt to specifically want the address of the first character of a particular index but then the compiler shows "warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast".

Comment: Don't you mean `char ** s =*extr,*p,*l=longstring;` ?

Comment: I think that char** s  would work for the first error, but now the second error is an issue... passing the extr parameter in.

Comment: `long extract()` does not return a value.  Check compiler warning settings.

Comment: `char ext[20][5000]; printf("%s\n",ext);` --> wrong type and UB.  Again, Save time - check compiler warning settings and insure they are enabled - or get a new compiler.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a scanset, `%[]`, to parse the string. The scan skips leading whitespace and then scans a `[`. Then the scanset reads characters that are not a `]`. Finally a `]` is scanned. The `%n` specifier reports the number of characters processed and that is added to offset to advance through the string. The 4999 prevents writing too many characters to the string [5000].

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int extract ( char* longstring,char (*extr)[5000]) {
    int used = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    int si = 0;

    while ( ( sscanf ( longstring + offset, " [%4999[^]]]%n", extr[si], &used)) == 1) {
         //one item successfully scanned
        si++;
        offset += used;
        if ( si > 20) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return si;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char ext[20][5000];
    int i = 0;
    int result = 0;

    result = extract("[a] [b] [ab] [abc]", ext);
    for ( i = 0; i < result; i++) {
        printf("ext[%d]  %s\n",i,ext[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```